# how i can play more than MP3 file in raw in my project in android studio? is there way?

Tags: android-studio, media-player, project

i mean if i have music.mp3 and music2.mp3 and music3.mp3 , how i can play them in raw file? what the code?, some body help please!

```
MediaPlayer mMedia = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
```

mMedia.start();

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to play them seperately!

Playing three Tracks synchronously using MediaPlayer will not work!

**Create three Mediaplayer Opjects:**

```
MediaPlayer mMp1;
MediaPlayer mMp2;
MediaPlayer mMp3;
```

.....

.....

```
    mMp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music1);
    mMp2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music2);
    mMp3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music3);
```

**Play them eg.: when a Button is clicked:**

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mBtnStart1.getId() == v.getId()) {
                    mMp1.start();
                    mMp2.pause();
                    mMp3.pause();
            }
    }
```

Same code for mMp2 and mMp3

There are several good tutorials on Youtube too:

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg7ib6S7ZkA)

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcrh8C376-c)

And you should definitely have a look on the MediaPlayer class on the developer page:

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)